# SCB_EnableDCache(); fails during run time in stm32

Tags: stm32, stm32f4discovery, stm32f7

I  am using NUCLEO-H755ZI-Q board, Which has two cores cortex m4 and cortex m7, To enable the lwip I have to enable CPU ICache and CPU DCache

[image]

But during runtime the program exits through SCB_EnableDCache(); function. Kindly help me if had missed something.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this issue. this was more specific to cube ide 1.7 when i rolled back to 1.6 it was working fine. Issue is with the code generation from cube mx

Answer (score 0):

Reference from [CMSIS-Core](https://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS/Core/html/group__Dcache__functions__m7.html#ga3861db932100ccb53f994e2cc68ed79c), the description for `__STATIC_FORCEINLINE void SCB_EnableDCache(void)`

> Before enabling the data cache, you must invalidate the entire data
> cache `SCB_InvalidateDCache()`, because external memory might have
> changed from when the cache was disabled. After reset, you must
> invalidate `SCB_InvalidateDCache()` each cache before enabling it.

So I think you can try to `SCB_InvalidateDCache()` before `SCB_EnableDCache()`.

On the other hand, can you provide the error message or the state of the error?

I think that helps figure out the root cause.

Comment: It was more specific with latest version of cubeide. rollback helped me in this